# Equivalent query from mysql to mongodb

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mongodb, nosql

```
JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id AND t1.date=t2.date
```

I am new to mongodb and I didn’t find a query to join two collections where I need to compare two fields from both collections.

Comment: Just as note, when you migrate an application from relational RDBMS like MySQL to a NoSQL database like MongoDB then usually the number of collections in MongoDB is much less than the number of tables in MySQL. Otherwise, you have done something fundamentally wrong. NoSQL databases are not optimized for joins, some of them do not support joins at all!